# Configuring JAX-RS With Spring Framework to Work on TomEE Virtual Hosts

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, apache-tomee

We are trying to deploy a jax-rs spring application to a tomee server with virtual hosts. However there seems to be an issue with the jax-rs service url that is bound to the application path

```
@Path("/api/test")
@Stateless
public class TestController extends BaseController {

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
```

And when deployed on the host it is accesible via localhost:8080/app-name/api/test/hello. But if we add virtual hosts to the mix, it would no longer be accessible through www.mywebsite.com/api/test/hello. We also added an index page to test if the virtual host is correctly configured and indeed you can access it via localhost:8080/app-name/Index.html and through www.mywebsite.com/Index.html.

It would seem that the context-path is wrong, however we cant find a way to fix it.